# Using mod_rewrite to simplify and shorten URL parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the following URL: `https://example.com/database?serial_number=XYZ`

Turned into `https://example.com/database/XYZ`

So far everything I have tried either didn't work, created redirect loop or threw server error 500.

"database" is a folder in root directory of the domain, inside of it is index.php file that accepts "serial_number" as a GET parameter, XYZ being sample data. The data is something the user would input, everything else is static.

I tried various methods including

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^database/([^/]*)$ /database/?serial_number=$1 [L]
```

I don't know if I just can't get it or it's because it is not a typical Apache server, but instead it runs on Nginx and supposedly has a custom Apache-like mod_rewrite compatibility also using .htaccess files.

**EDIT:**

Solved! Thank you @Anuga in comments. The correct code is following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^database/([A-Za-z0-9]{8}+)$ database/?serial_number=$1 [L]
```

Please note that I have added {8} to the regular expression since that's part of my requirement (value has to be exactly 8 characters long). Another failure point was adding this code at the end of .htaccess file, which for some reason made it work improperly, most likely due to some HTTPS code that's there.

I also recommend using this tool: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/
It lets you test the rule very efficiently without constantly sending it to target server.

Comment: @Anuga I managed to solve it, partially thanks to your invaluable suggestion and partially to a great tool that allows faster testing of the rules: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ Thank you.